# Visualizing range of possible CDFs of $X\in (0,1]$ such that $E[X]=1/3$

Tags: probability-or-statistics, visualization

What's an elegant way to visualize the range of possible CDFs for a random variable $X\in (0,1]$ such that $E[X]=\frac{1}{3}$?

Below is an attempt by discretizing (0,1] interval and using `FindInstance` but it fails to scale past `d=10`. This is just a a simple linearly constrained problem, wondering if there's a way to get `FindInstance` to use specialized solver in this setting.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 5; (* number of discrete values *)
mean = 1/3; (* target expected value E[x]=mean *)
meanVec = N@Rest@Subdivide[d]; (* discrete values like 0.1,.2,...,1 *)
Clear[x]; vars = Array[x, d];
cons = Join @@ {0 <= # & /@ vars, {Total[vars] == 1, 
     meanVec . vars == mean}};
points = vars /. FindInstance[cons, vars, 40];

cdf[vals_] := {meanVec, Accumulate[vals]}\[Transpose]
ListLinePlot[cdf /@ points, AxesLabel -> {"X"}, 
 PlotLabel -> StringForm["CDFs of distr with mean ``", mean]]
```

[image]

Also tried ImplicitRegion, but it returns unevaluated

```
d = 3; (* number of bins *)
Clear[x]; vars = Array[x, d];
meanVec = Rest@Subdivide[d]; (* 0.1,.2,...,1 *)
positiveOrthant = 
  ImplicitRegion @@ {And @@ (0 <= # & /@ vars), vars};
normalizedRegion = ImplicitRegion @@ {Total[vars] == 1, vars}
meanRegion = ImplicitRegion @@ {vars . meanVec == 1/3, vars}
RandomPoint[
 RegionIntersection[positiveOrthant, normalizedRegion, meanRegion]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Simplify @ Mean[BetaDistribution[a, a (1 - μ)/μ]]
```

> ```
> μ
> ```

So we can use `CDF[BetaDistribution[α, 2 α]` (for $\alpha>0$) to get a one-parameter family of cdfs:

```
With[{μ = 1/3}, 
 Plot[Evaluate[Through[(CDF[BetaDistribution[#, # (1 - μ)/μ]] & /@ 
     Subdivide[1/20, 10, 30]) @ x]], 
  {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> Subdivide[1/20, 10, 30]]]
```

[image]

With `μ = 2/3` we get

[image]

If you wish you can expand the family arbitrarily by taking mixtures of `BetaDistribution[α, 2 α]`:

```
md[a_List, p_List] := MixtureDistribution[p, BetaDistribution[#, 2 #] & /@ a];

Simplify @ Mean[md[{a, b, c}, {p, q, 1 - p - q}]]
```

> ```
> 1/3
> ```

```
With[{a = {2, 20}}, 
  Legended[Row[
    Table[Plot[Evaluate[
     Through[(f[md[a, {#, 1 - #}]] & /@ Subdivide[10])@x]], 
      {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> f, ImageSize -> 400],
    {f, {PDF, CDF}}]], 
   LineLegend[97, Subdivide[10], LegendLabel -> Style["p", 16]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist1 = TruncatedDistribution[{0, 1},
   NormalDistribution[m1, σ1]];

param1 = 
  FindInstance[{Mean[dist1] == 1/3, σ1 > 0, 0 < m1 < 1},
    {m1, σ1}, RandomSeeding -> 1234][[1]];

cdf1 = Assuming[0 < x <= 1, CDF[dist1 /. param1, x] // FullSimplify];

dist2 = TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, c2];

param2 = Solve[Mean[dist2] == 1/3, c2][[1]];

cdf2 = Assuming[0 < x <= 1, CDF[dist2 /. param2, x] // Simplify];

dist3 = BetaDistribution[α, β];

param3 = SortBy[
    FindInstance[{Mean[dist3] == 1/3, α > 0, β > 
       0}, {α, β}, 20, RandomSeeding -> 1234],
    Variance[
      dist3 /. #] &][[-5 ;;]];
(* select dist3 with largest variance *)

cdf3 = Assuming[0 < x < 1, 
   CDF[#, x] & /@ (dist3 /. param3) // Simplify];

dist4 = PowerDistribution[1, a];

param4 = Solve[Mean[dist4] == 1/3, a][[1]];

cdf4 = Assuming[0 < x < 1, CDF[dist4 /. param4, x] // Simplify];

Plot[Evaluate@Flatten[{cdf1, cdf2, cdf3, cdf4}],
  {x, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a piecewise-linear CDF by adding together a bunch of "unit ramps", which we define as:

```
unitramp[x_, {loc_, width_}] = 
 Piecewise[{{(x - loc)/width + 1/2, -1/2 <= (x - loc)/width <= 
     1/2}, {1, (x - loc)/width >= 1/2}, {0, (x - loc)/width <= 1/2}}]
```

Here, `loc` is the location of the center of the ramp (between `0` and `1`), and `width` is its width.  `width` must be chosen so that the "ends" of the ramp both fall within the range $[0,1]$.  The EV for this CDF will obviously be `loc`.

So we can construct a "random CDF" with the desired properties as follows:

- Randomly select some number of locations $x_i$ for the ramps.
- Randomly select a width $\delta_i$ for each ramp.
- Find a set of weights $w_i > 0$ for each "ramp" such that $\sum w_i = 1$ and $\sum x_i w_i = \frac13$.  (Note that this will not be possible if all the $x_i$ values are greater than 1/3 or less than 1/3, so we may have to discard a candidate location set in this process.)
- Plot the sum of all of our ramps, weighted by the weights $w_i$.

Code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
unitramp[x_, {loc_, width_}] = 
 Piecewise[{{(x - loc)/width + 1/2, -1/2 <= (x - loc)/width <= 
     1/2}, {1, (x - loc)/width >= 1/2}, {0, (x - loc)/width <= 1/2}}]
randomcdf[n_] := Block[{locations, widths, weightsol},
  weightsol = {};
  (* n = number of ramps in construction *)
  While[Length[weightsol] == 0,
   locations = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
   widths = RandomReal[{0, Min[#, 1 - #]}] & /@ locations;
   weightsol = 
    First[FindInstance[
      Join[{Sum[w[i], {i, n}] == 1, 
        Sum[locations[[i]] w[i], {i, n}] == 1/3}, 
       Table[w[i] > 0, {i, n}]], Table[w[i], {i, n}]]];
   ];
  foo = Map[(#[[3]] unitramp[x, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}]) &, 
    Transpose[{locations, widths, 
      Table[w[i], {i, n}] /. weightsol}]];
  PiecewiseExpand[Total[foo]]
  ]
cdflist = Table[randomcdf[RandomInteger[{5, 20}]], 30];
(* Between 5 & 20 ramps in each CDF **)
Show[Table[
  Plot[cdflist[[i]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][i], 
   MaxRecursion -> 10], {i, Length[cdflist]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]